# C count numbers entered separated by commas

Tags: c, loops, csv, count

I have a code that checks if number is odd or even. I use char to input and separate each number with commas. Everything works great, but I need to count how many numbers have been entered and how many of them are even numbers.
I ran into a wall because of commas. I tried to search google, but my english is not so good and I can't find such function. Maybe I should loop number entries until user simply press enter to start checking even numbers and odd numbers. My code so far:

```
char str[256];
 fgets (str, 256, stdin);
    char *pt;
    pt = strtok (str,",");
    while (pt != NULL) {
        int a = atoi(pt);

        if (a%2 == 0)
        {
            printf("Number is even\n");

        }
        else
        {
            printf("Number is odd!\n\n");
        }
        printf("%d\n", a);
        pt = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }
```

Comment: You are already detecting even/odd numbers. Why can't you just have counters `total_count` and `num_even_count` and increment those in the appropriate places? It's not clear what your difficulty is.

Comment: I don't understand. You still have a loop on numbers. Why don't you use a counter in the while loop to know the number of values? Just ++ it in "even" and "odd" allows easely to count odds and evens (total should be even+odd).

Comment: @kaylum I am learning C and did not know about num_even_count. I was using what I have learned so far. I will try that. I was very confused with waht to do wiht commas.

Comment: Should you increment `pt` after call to `strtok (NULL, ",");`?

Comment: TDWTF? there's no magical num_even_count, @kaylum just made up a variable name that seems appropriate for counting ...

Comment: @FiddlingBits to what purpose? `pt` will point to the first character after delimiter.

Comment: @WeatherVane Will `atoi` work properly if the `pt` is pointing to a `,`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because answers would have to give a "general primer on programming", which isn't helpful for future readers.

Comment: @FiddlingBits `pt` is not pointing to a `,`

Comment: @WeatherVane Nevermind.  Was thinking of `strchr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we use variable++ that means increment value of variable by 1.

```
char str[256];
fgets (str, 256, stdin);
char *pt;
int odd_count = 0,even_count = 0;
pt = strtok (str,",");
while (pt != NULL) {
    int a = atoi(pt);

    if (a%2 == 0)
    {
        printf("Number is even\n");
        even_count++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Number is odd!\n\n");
        odd_count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", a);
    pt = strtok (NULL, ",");
}
printf("Count of even numbers in the sequence is %d",even_count);
printf("Count of odd numbers in the sequence is %d",odd_count);
printf("Total numbers in the sequence is are %d",even_count + odd_count);
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, as you read in each number count the total number of values read in.  Then when you do the check for an even number, increments another counter for that:

```
int countTotal = 0, countEven = 0;
while (pt != NULL) {
    int a = atoi(pt);

    countTotal++;
    if (a%2 == 0)
    {
        printf("Number is even\n");
        countEven++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Number is odd!\n\n");
    }
    printf("%d\n", a);
    pt = strtok (NULL, ",");
}
```